# Is there an easy way default construct a generic type in C++, without an allocator instance?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, c++14

The context is:
Writing a container, containing type T, and a char * p to a memory region. Let's suppose the pointer is already suitably aligned for type T - the alignment issue is not part of the question.
How do I default construct an element on that memory region?

```
((*T)(p))->T();
```

works for classes, but not with some builtin types.

```
((*T)(p)) = 0; // or simply memset
```

for integral types, pointers.
Do these two cover everything, unions and what not?
Is there a best practice for this, or some standard library feature?
std::allocator::construct can do it, that is what e.g. std::vector uses, but it is not a static method, so I would need an instance of it. Is there some freestanding or static function that can do it?

--EDIT--

Yes, the answer is obvious, and I was dumb today -- placement new
BTW, Now I'm trying to destroy the element...

Comment: Placement new: `new (p) T();`

Comment: That first snippet should not compile...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

Comment: Concerning the edit: There is no `delete` equivalent for placment-new. For classes, pure destruction is done by an explicit destructor call `myFooPtr->~Foo();`. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for builtin types, so I guess, you are out of luck at that point. However, since you seem not to be afraid of heavy templates, you might use SFINAE to distinguish between the cases that a destructor can or cannot be called, and instanciate code with/without such a destructor call accordingly (builtin types don't need destruction). Beware of array types, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Placement new" is the term to look for. It is a standard library `operator new` overload that does not actually allocate memory, but just returns whatever pointer you pass to it.

Comment: this very closely resembles a comment. In fact it closely resembles the comment that is also already there.

Comment: @sehe Look at the timestamps. I was clearly already typing my answer when that comment was posted.

Comment: Now I'm trying to destroy the item... back to square one

Comment: You can explicitly call the destructor for that.

Comment: @BuellaGábor you can call the destructor of an object from a pointer to the object with `myfooptr->~Foo();`

Comment: placement new works for builtin types as well as for classes, but int has no destructor....

Comment: @BuellaGabor Look up "pseudo-destructor call". I am guessing you tested with a simple typedef. In that case you already know in advance that you do not need to call the destructor. In the general case, when `T` is not known in advance, the syntax gets accepted even for simple types.

Comment: right, it works, I just had a typo before. I'v never heard of a pseudo destructor before, thx!

Answer (score 3):

Include the `<new>` header and use its placement new allocation function like this:

```
::new (p) T()
```

The `::`  qualification avoids picking up a class-specific allocation function.

The paranthesis `(p)` is an argument list for the allocation function.

This allocation function just returns the passed in pointer.

To be pedantic about things you would also cast the pointer to `void*`, to avoid picking up some hypothetical other `operator new` in the global namespace.

---

The code shown in the question, `((*T)(p))->T();`, should not compile. The standard explicitly points out that a constructor doesn't have a name. So it can't be called like an ordinary function.